# Performance difference between mutating struct and reassigning struct

Tags: swift, performance, optimization

Consider the following struct in swift:

```
struct Point {
   var x:Float
   var y:Float
   mutating func add(x:Float) {
      self.x += x
   }
}
```

I am curious if there will be any performance difference between the following:

Option A:

```
var p = Point(x:0,y:0)
p.add(x:1)
```

Option B

```
var p = Point(x:0,y:0)
p = Point(x:p.x+1,y:p.y)
```

In particular I am wondering if the compiler is smart enough in Option B to simply mutate p without creating a new instance of Point.

Comment: declare all your structure properties as constants and if you need to update the values just create a new instance with the updated values

Comment: Btw why are you using Float? You should always use Double and Int when coding in Swift if you don't have a specific reason for using other numeric types.

Comment: This is just a hypothetical. I want to understand if the compiler optimizes struct mutations in the way I indicated.

Comment: if you are looking for optimization don't mutate. Create a new instance `struct Point {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}
extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
    static let zero: Point = .init(x: 0, y: 0)
    func adding(x: Double) -> Point {
        return .init(x: self.x + x, y: y)
    }
    func adding(y: Double) -> Point {
        return .init(x: x, y: self.y + y)
    }
    var description: String {
        return "Point(x: \(x), y: \(y))"
    }
}

let pointA: Point = .zero
let pointB = pointA.adding(x: 1)
pointB  // Point(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)`

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate? It seems unintuitive that instance creation would be faster than mutation, especially if the struct has many members and you are only changing one or two members.

Comment: You would really need to profile this in the context in which you want to use it. I tried to come up with a "general" answer by playing around with [godbolt](https://swift.godbolt.org), but how the value is consumed drastically changes the compiled code.

Comment: You should mark the `add(x:)` function with `mutating`

Comment: ielyamani yes thanks.

Comment: Agreed with @Alexander. There is no general answer to this question. In your option B, though, you wouldn't expect the compiler to mutate `p`. You'd expect it to never allocate the first `Point` at all. Point is going to be completely stack allocated anyway (so the entire Point struct may be optimized away, all of it). This is a incredibly special case that can't be generalized to "mutating vs reassigning" performance. Profile profile profile, and also look at the optimized SIL (-O --emit-sil) to see what kinds of things swiftc does in your specific, concrete case.